# Effects of the Spring Constant on Angular Frequency in Simple Harmonic Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring

The formula for the angular frequency of a spring-block system in SHM is:

[image]

Why does a larger "k" value lead to a larger angular frequency (and a lower period)? Wouldn't a large k value lead to a stiffer spring, which would cause the spring to move slower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stiffer spring (larger $k$) means that for a given extension the force exerted by the spring is larger than for a less stiff spring (smaller $k$).
This in turn means that the acceleration of the mass is larger for a stiffer spring and so the speed of the mass reaches a larger value.
So on average the speed of the mass is larger which results in the mass travelling a given distance in a shorter period of time ie the period is smaller than for a less stiff spring.

Answer (score 1):

A stiffer spring means more force is needed to extend/compress it.  Hence, the restoring force of the spring back to its equilibrium position is greater; acceleration is greater.  Hence period is definitely lower, as the spring moves faster.